# Return total number of files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: python, recursion, count, subdirectory, pathlib

Trying to create a function that returns the # of files found a directory and its subdirectories. Just need help getting started

Answer (score 108):

One - liner

```
import os
cpt = sum([len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk("G:\CS\PYTHONPROJECTS")])
```

Comment: Could you explain why you need the sum function? Why wouldn't len(files) be sufficient?

Comment: @GWarner There are multiple sets of files (from each subdirectory) that are yielded by os.walk. You must sum over the length of each set to get the amount of files.  If you use len(files) then you get a list where each element is the number of files in its associated subdirectory.

Comment: note you need to use forward slashes (or \\\) instead of back slashes as you have here, otherwise python thinks you're using escapes.

Answer (score 31):

Use `os.walk`. It will do the recursion for you. See http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/code-snippets-source-code/python-os-walk/ for an example.

```
total = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
    total += len(files)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just add an `elif` statement that takes care of the directories:

```
def fileCount(folder):
    "count the number of files in a directory"

    count = 0

    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        path = os.path.join(folder, filename)

        if os.path.isfile(path):
            count += 1
        elif os.path.isfolder(path):
            count += fileCount(path)

    return count
```

Comment: `os.path.isdir` works for me on Ubuntu instead of `os.path.isfolder`.

Answer (score 2):

- Here are some one-liners using [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html), which is part of the standard library.
- Use `Path.cwd().rglob('*')` or `Path('some path').rglob('*')`, which creates a generator of all the files.

  - Unpack the generator with `list` or `*`, and use `len` to get the number of files.
- See [How to count total number of files in each subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57679565/7758804) to get the total number of files for each directory.

```py
from pathlib import Path

total_dir_files = len(list(Path.cwd().rglob('*')))

# or 
total_dir_files = len([*Path.cwd().rglob('*')])

# or filter for only files using is_file()
file_count = len([f for f in Path.cwd().rglob('*') if f.is_file()])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a time-test for the 3 most popular methods:

```
import os
from datetime import datetime

dir_path = "D:\\Photos"

# os.listdir

def recursive_call(dir_path):
    folder_array = os.listdir(dir_path)
    files = 0
    folders = 0
    for path in folder_array:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
            files += 1
        elif os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir_path, path)):
            folders += 1
            file_count, folder_count = recursive_call(os.path.join(dir_path, path))
            files += file_count
            folders += folder_count
    return files, folders
start_time = datetime.now()
files, folders = recursive_call(dir_path)
print ("\nFolders: %d, Files: %d" % (folders, files))
print ("Time Taken (os.listdir): %s seconds" % (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds())

# os.walk

start_time = datetime.now()
file_array = [len(files) for r, d, files in os.walk(dir_path)]
files = sum(file_array)
folders = len(file_array)
print ("\nFolders: %d, Files: %d" % (folders, files))
print ("Time Taken (os.walk): %s seconds" % (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds())

# os.scandir

def recursive_call(dir_path):
    folder_array = os.scandir(dir_path)
    files = 0
    folders = 0
    for path in folder_array:
        if path.is_file():
            files += 1
        elif path.is_dir():
            folders += 1
            file_count, folder_count = recursive_call(path)
            files += file_count
            folders += folder_count
    return files, folders
start_time = datetime.now()
files, folders = recursive_call(dir_path)
print ("\nFolders: %d, Files: %d" % (folders, files))
print ("Time Taken (os.scandir): %s seconds" % (datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds())
```

Results:

```
Folders: 53, Files: 29048
Time Taken (os.listdir): 3.074945 seconds

Folders: 53, Files: 29048
Time Taken (os.walk): 0.062022 seconds

Folders: 53, Files: 29048
Time Taken (os.scandir): 0.048984 seconds
```

Conclusion:

While `os.walk` is the most elegant, `os.scandir` recursively implemented seems to be the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is My Version**

```
def fileCount(folder, allowed_extensions=None):
   "count the number of files in a directory and sub directory"
   count = 0
   for base, dirs, files in os.walk(folder):
      for file in files:
         if allowed_extensions and file.endswith(allowed_extensions) or not allowed_extensions:
            count += 1
   return count
```

`scan_dir = r"C:\Users\sannjayy\Desktop"`

`allowed_extensions = (".jpg", ".mp4")`

`print(fileCount(scan_dir , allowed_extensions))`