# How to count total number of files in each subfolder

Tags: python, pathlib

My file structure looks like this:

```
- Outer folder
  - Inner folder 1
    - Files...
  - Inner folder 2
    - Files...
  - …
```

I'm trying to count the total number of files in the whole of Outer folder. `os.walk` doesn't return any files when I pass it the Outer folder, and as I've only got two layers I've written it manually:

```py
total = 0
folders = ([name for name in os.listdir(Outer_folder)
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(Outer_folder, name))])
for folder in folders:
    contents = os.listdir(os.path.join(Outer_folder, folder))
    total += len(contents)
print(total)
```

Is there a better way to do this? And can I find the number of files in an arbitrarily nested set of folders? I can't see any examples of deeply nested folders on Stack Overflow.

By 'better', I mean some kind of built in function, rather than manually writing something to iterate - e.g. an `os.walk` that walks the whole tree.

Answer (score 7):

### Use `pathlib`:

- [Return total number of files in directory and subdirectories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73544506/7758804) shows how to get just the total number.
- [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) is part of the
  standard library, and should be used instead of `os` because it treats paths as objects with methods, not strings to be sliced.
- [Python 3's pathlib Module: Taming the File System](https://realpython.com/python-pathlib/)
- Use a condition to select only files:

  - `[x.parent for x in f if x.is_file()]`

#### File and subdirectory count in each directory:

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np

p = Path.cwd()  # if you're running in the current dir
# p = Path('path to to dir')  # otherwise, specify a path 

# creates a generator of all the files matching the pattern
f = p.rglob('*')
# optionally, use list(...) to unpack the generator
# f = list(p.rglob('*'))

# counts them
paths, counts = np.unique([x.parent for x in f], return_counts=True)

path_counts = list(zip(paths, counts))
```

#### Output:

- List of tuples with path and count

```
[(WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow'), 8),
 (WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/.ipynb_checkpoints'), 7),
 (WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/complete_solutions/data'), 6),
 (WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/csv_files'), 3),
 (WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/csv_files/.ipynb_checkpoints'), 1),
 (WindowsPath('E:/PythonProjects/stack_overflow/data'), 5)]
```

- `f = list(p.rglob('*'))` unpacks the generator and produces a list of all the files.

#### One-liner:

- Use `Path.cwd().rglob('*')` or `Path('some path').rglob('*')`

```py
path_counts = list(zip(*np.unique([x.parent for x in Path.cwd().rglob('*')], return_counts=True)))
```

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you use recursion as the function below:

```
def get_folder_count(path):
    folders = os.listdir(path)
    folders = list(filter(lambda a: os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, a)), folders))
    count = len(folders)
    for i in range(count):
        count += get_folder_count(os.path.join(path, folders[i]))
    return count
```