# How to create a python list with the number of file in each sub directory of a directory

Tags: python, list, listdir

I have a main directory(root) which countain 6 sub directory.
I would like to **count the number of files present in each sub directory and add all to a simple python list**.

For this result :       mylist = [497643, 5976, 3698, 12, 456, 745]

I'm blocked on that code:

```
import os, sys
list = []
# Open a file
path = "c://root"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   print (file)

#fill a list with each sub directory number of elements
for sub_dir in dirs:
    list = dirs.append(len(sub_dir))
```

My trying for the list fill doesn't work and i'm dramaticaly at my best...

Finding a way to iterate sub-directory of a main directory and fill a list with a function applied on each sub directory would sky rocket the speed of my actual data science project!

Thanks for your help

Abel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return number of files in directory and subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16910330/return-number-of-files-in-directory-and-subdirectory)

Comment: Using `os.walk()` will help a lot. It recursively drills down sub directories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [os.path.isfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isfile) and [os.path.isdir](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)

```
res = [len(list(map(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.path.join(path, name))))) for name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))]
print(res)
```

Using the for loop

```
res = []
for name in os.listdir(path):
    dir_path = os.path.join(path, name)
    if os.path.isdir(dir_path):
        res.append(len(list(map(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(dir_path)))))
```

Comment: With these two solutions, i have that error message: 
      7 list = []
----> 8 res = [len(list(map(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(os.path.join(path, name))))) for name in os.listdir(path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(path, name))]
      9 print(res)

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: you have used `list` as a variable name somewhere in your code that's why you are getting the error. don't use this `list = []` change the name to something else it will work

Answer (score 0):

You need to use os.listdir on each subdirectory. The current code simply takes the length of a filepath.

```
import os, sys
list = []
# Open a file
path = "c://root"
dirs = os.listdir( path )

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
   print (file)

#fill a list with each sub directory number of elements
for sub_dir in dirs:
    temp = os.listdir(sub_dir)
    list = dirs.append(len(temp))
```

Adding this line to the code will list out the subdirectory

Comment: If you have subdirectories in your subdirectories, you'll need to use the solution linked by @sushanth

Comment: ```FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-9c2850a395c0> in <module>
     11 #fill a list with each sub directory number of elements
     12 for sub_dir in dirs:
---> 13     temp = os.listdir(sub_dir)
     14     list = dirs.append(len(temp))

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable: 'AMARYLLIDACEAE'

Comment: I have that error with this line of code added. Considering 'AMARYLLIDACEAE' is the first sub directory.

I work on Jupyter notebook

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there:

```
import os, sys

list = []

# Open a file
path = "c://root"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

# This would print all the files and directories
for file in dirs:
    print(file)

for sub_dir in dirs:
    if os.path.isdir(sub_dir):
        list.append(len(os.listdir(os.path.join(path, sub_dir))))

print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you can also utilize `glob` module for this and other related tasks.
I have created a `test` directory containing 3 subdirectories `l`,`m` and `k` containing 3 test files each.

```
import os, glob
  
list = []
path = "test" # you can leave this "." if you want files in the current directory

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=True):
   for name in dirs:
     list.append(len(glob.glob(root + '/' +  name + '/*')))

print(list)
```

Output :

```
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Your solution is close to be the better for my problem:)
It create two list in a list: the first with the complete path + name of files and the second with the number of file in each directory. I just need the second list and i know how to delete the first list.

But how to directly create a simple list wtih just the number of file in each sub directory? (without path and directory)

Comment: @Abel I have updated the code. You need `path` because you need to start somewhere. You can leave it to be `"."` for the current directory. Then, `os.walk` will do the job for you.